# create an array from json and referencing id to type

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, json

How do i create an array from this json that would associate ATTRIBUTE_TYPE to ATTRIBUTE ID.
Right now i am being returned the following json:

```
(
    [success] => 1
    [ATTRIBUTES_COUNT] => 106
    [ATTRIBUTES] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ATTRIBUTE_TYPE] => email
                    [DATA_TYPE] => CHAR
                    [COMPARE_COUNT] => 2
                    [COMPARE] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (

                                    [ATTRIBUTE_ID] => 4222
                                    [DESCR] => Equals
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (

                                    [ATTRIBUTE_ID] => 4223
                                    [DESCR] => Not Equal
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ATTRIBUTE_TYPE] => interest
                    [DATA_TYPE] => MONEY
                    [COMPARE_COUNT] => 7
                    [COMPARE] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (

                                    [ATTRIBUTE_ID] => 4006
                                    [COMPARE_DESCR] => Not Equal
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (

                                    [ATTRIBUTE_ID] => 4000
                                    [COMPARE_DESCR] => Equals
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (

                                    [ATTRIBUTE_ID] => 4001
                                    [COMPARE_DESCR] => Greater Than
                                )

                       )

                )
)
```

now I want to create an array that would return something like this after json_decode:

```
{
    "DETAILS": [
        {

            "ATTRIBUTE_ID": "4222",
            "ATTRIBUTE_TYPE": "email",

        },
        {

            "ATTRIBUTE_ID": "4006",
            "ATTRIBUTE_TYPE": "interest",


        }
    ]
}
```

the same attribute type can have multiple attribute ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particularly elegant, but give this a try ($inputArray is the deeply-nested array you posted at the top of your question):

```
$desiredArray = array("DETAILS" => array());

foreach($inputArray["ATTRIBUTES"] as $attribute)
{
    foreach($attribute["COMPARE"] as $compare)
    {
        $desiredArray["DETAILS"][] = array("ATTRIBUTE_ID" => $compare["ATTRIBUTE_ID"],
            "ATTRIBUTE_TYPE" => $attribute["ATTRIBUTE_TYPE"]);
    }
}

$desiredJson = json_encode($desiredArray);
```